# Reading a Text File and Reacting (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I looked for quite a while and couldn't find a good solution to my problem. I want a batch program to "look" in a .txt file for the command "" and if that word is in it, then to execute a different command. If the command existed, I would want to do something like `set %textfile%=text.txt` and if that worked I would then do `if %textfile%==update goto update` which would be an easy way to start an automatic update if this was in a loop. So basically, is there a command that sets a text file in %text%? This is the code that I am trying to add this into:

```
@echo off
color 0f
:start
echo Welcome to Master control pannel
ping 127.1 -n 4 >nul
cls
:options
cls
echo What would you like to do first? (Type the number of the operation you want to start)
echo.
ping 127.1 -n 2 >nul
echo 1. Run a command off of all computers 
::(I want to run a command by sending a message to a text file but want recieving computor to be able to read it and execute it, how could I read the command and then do what it say, for example, if the command says "echo Hello" I would want recieving computor to say "Hello" )
echo 2. Stops the current command
echo 3. List all computers
echo 4. Open remote shutdown program
echo 5. Delete a computor (in progress) 
echo 6. (Unfinished)
echo 7. (Unfinished)
echo 8. (Unfinished)
echo 9. (Unfinished)
echo 10. Exit
set /p choose=(1-9):
if %choose%==1 goto o1
if %choose%==2 goto o2
if %choose%==3 goto o3
if %choose%==4 goto o4
if %choose%==5 goto o5
if %choose%==6 goto close
if %choose%==7 goto close
if %choose%==8 goto close
if %choose%==9 goto close
if %choose%==10 goto o10
goto options
:close
cls
goto start
:o1
echo Stopping current command
del command.txt
echo. 2>command.txt
echo Command stopped!
pause
cls
goto start
```

I would greatly appreciate some help or comments to what I could do or add to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer but several hints.

- a variable can hold only single lines not a whole file.
- if you want to get the first line of a file into a var use `Set /P "var="

  `set %textfile%=text.txt` would store `test.txt` literally into a var whose name is the content of the var `textfile`.

  you are mixing `goto o1` and `:01` with the label

`